# Wondering why pointer arithmetic not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, math, pointers

I wanted to try pointer arithmetic in c#. I have used an asp.net web app, expecting that it wouldn't matter if it was this or a console app.

here is what I tried:

```
public class memorytest
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public int A;
        public int B;
        public int C;
        public int D;
    }

   public static unsafe void Main()
   {
    Sample s = new Sample {A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4};
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int* pA = &a;
    int* pB = &b;
    Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",* pB);
    Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB - 1));
    Debug.WriteLine(*pA);
    Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB - 2));
    }

}
```

The result was like this:

0000000000000002,
0000000004b5ca00,
1,
0000000004b5c9fc,

I was obviously expecting the second one to be the number 1. Does anybody understand this?

Comment: In C and C++, this is undefined behaviour. How do you expect anything less from an ecosystem where you have even less control over the memory layout?

Comment: You can even use native methods for allocating memory in c#/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, if you want to learn how the stack is laid out, it seems like it would be a lot easier to *start the debugger* and look at the stack in the debugger.

Assuming that for some reason you want to keep on writing programs to examine their own stack state: you stopped experimenting too early. The program you should have written is:

```
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB - 1));
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB + 0));    
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB + 1));
```

and then you would have gotten the output

```
00000badf00dd00d  <-- some pointer value
0000000000000002  <-- contents of b
0000000000000001  <-- contents of a
```

and you would have learned that *stacks grow in the opposite direction that you think they do*. In many architectures pushing something onto the stack *decreases* the stack pointer.

Of course, as others have pointed out, we make no guarantees whatsoever as to how stuff is laid out on the stack, or even if stuff goes onto the stack in the first place; local variables may be placed on the heap in some situations, and local variables whose addresses are never taken may be enregistered. For example, what happens if you don't take the address of "a"? Does it still end up on the stack? Maybe not!

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's the answer to my question.

Comment: I hadn't realized until now that taking the address of a variable actually changes it because you can't take the address of a register. Thanks for the "Aha!" moment just now.

Comment: @configurator: Indeed. The optimizer has to do all sorts of work to figure out how best to allocate a small number of registers (in the x86 architecture) to a large number of locals and temporaries. It is pretty good about guessing correctly. Taking the address of a local is of course an operation that prevents the optimizer from enregistering that local.

Answer (score 6):

This problem is unrelated to ASP.net. Your usage of pointer arithmetic is simply wrong.

How the local variables are layed out on the stack(or if they are even on the stack) is unspecified an almost any programming language.

A few complications in the storage of logical local variables:

- Most compilers will put local variables in a register unless you get their address.
- variables bound by a lambda, or variables in a `async` method are on heap objects.
- Even when they are indeed on the stack the order is arbitrary.
- There is not even a 1 to 1 correspondence between logical variables and memory locations. A memory location can be reused once a variable goes out of scope.

Pointer arithmetic can usually only be used within a single allocated memory block.

So the result of `*(pB - 1)` which dereferences the memory in front of `b` is unspecified behavior.

In .net you typically can use pointer arithmetic inside arrays or manually allocated memory blocks.

Comment: @the_law Do you have any source that specifies the layout of local variables on the stack? I doubt such thing exists.

Comment: CodeInChaos, that's what this is about. The tutorial I am working through says that the locals are place sequentially on the stack, so you can find a variable by incrementing to it.            geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/13/speedy-c-part-3-understanding-memory-references-pinned-objects-and.aspx. But you might be talking about the absolute position in memory, not just where the variables lie relative to eachother.

Comment: That they are sequentially on the stack is not guaranteed. It just happened to be that way for the code and version of the runtime the author of that blog happened to run it on.

Comment: @the_law: CodeInChaos is absolutely right here. Though it is *common* for locals to be laid out on the stack in the order they appear in source code, there is absolutely no *requirement* that they be arranged in any particular way, or even that they go on the stack at all.  It's perfectly reasonable to examine memory to learn about how this stuff works, but you absolutely should not be writing code that *depends* on it.

Comment: I suppose you are right, as evidenced by the fact that to get this working as shown in the tutorial, I have to switch decrementing and incrementing around.

Answer (score 4):

Your second reference is dereferencing the address of pB - 1, rather than dereferencing pB and subtracting 1.

For the second line to return you a value of 1, it would need to read like this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB) - 1);
```

Comment: Sry I made it confusing. I was trying to test if *(pB - 1) = a; the assumpution being that they are placed sequentially on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can or should make any assumptions about WHERE in memory .NET places your variables. In your case `*pB` correctly resolves to `2` since that's the value of `b`. I don't think you can assume `a` will be allocated 'before' `b` such that `*(pB - 1)` points to it. You're seeing the integer value of 'whatever is one `int` before `b` on the stack.'

Comment: I was basing it on this: geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/13/speedy-c-part-3-understanding-memory-references-pinned-objects-and.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",*(pB - 1));
```

You're taking the value of the memory location of `pB - 1`. Not the value of `pB` minus one.

Try using this:

```
Debug.WriteLine("{0:x16}",(*(pB) - 1));
```

Comment: Thx, i will try this soon-ish. I got this code from here btw: geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/08/13/speedy-c-part-3-understanding-memory-references-pinned-objects-and.aspx

Comment: I made it confusing by chosing the numbers that I chose. I was trying to do pointer arithmetic, assuming that a is stored right behind b on the stack.